# Spring Boot how to add another resources folder in test folder

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, classpath

Is it possible to add another resources folder in test folder, which will also be on the classpath?
I need it because I don't want to add application-test.properties file in default resources folder because it belongs in test folder.

I tried to add folder manually but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I soloved this problem, in Intellij IDEA by:

Right clicking on the project -> Projectu structure,
and I marked newlycreated folder as Resources file.

Comment: It is ok until the project will be imported by another user.

Comment: Will it be ok if someone fetch project from github and uses different IDE (eclipse)?

Answer (score 0):

It is gradle project or maven? If you have gradle just add the line below to the `build.gradle` file:

```
ext {
    resourcesDir = projectDir.path + "/other/resources"
}
```

where the `/other/resources` is your dedicated resource folder

Comment: No, it's not Gradle, it is a Maven project.